# MongoDB $pull from nested array based on a set of criteria

Tags: mongodb

Okay, so I'm looking to update all documents matching the below query:

```
var searchArray = ["AH Refer"
];
db.ReasonTest.find({ 
$and: [
    {
        "Values.Reason": {
            $in: searchArray
        }
    },
    {
        "Values.Modules": {
            $all: ["Provider Search"]
        }
    }
]
});
```

My document structure looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("537398e92db5868b145f5f29"),
"ID" : NumberLong(1),
"Name" : "MCC",
"Values" : [ 
    {
        "ID" : NumberLong(1016),
        "Reason" : "COB",
        "Modules" : [ 
            "SRA"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "ID" : NumberLong(104),
        "Reason" : "AH Refer",
        "Modules" : [ 
            "Provider Search"
        ]

    }
]
}
```

And basically, what I want to do, is find all Reasons (the root document), which has one of the values above (e.g. "AH Refer") in the Reason field of the Values array.  If they have "Provider Search" in the Modules array, I want to remove "Provider Search" from the Modules array on that value in "Values".  I'm having a really tough time with it for this client.  Obviously their structure is not ideal (nested array support is not very good in Mongo), but I'm hoping one of you wizkids can help me out.  Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the descriptions on the bottom of question,
my comprehension on query part is : both `Reason` and `Modules` conform the criteria
in the same element of "Values", then the document is that needs to update.
So, I modified the query part with `$elemMatch` accordingly.

```
var searchArray = [ "AH Refer to CMC: Claims Inquiry",
        "AH Refer to CMC:  Eligibility Inquiry",
        "AH Refer to CMC: Requested Benefit Information",
        "After Hours - Referred to CMC", "After Hours Referred to RHBA" ];

var moduleValue = "Provider Search";

while (db.ReasonTest_Kyle.update({
    Values : {
        $elemMatch : {
            Reason : {
                $in : searchArray
            },
            Modules : moduleValue
        }
    }
}, {
    $pull : {
        "Values.$.Modules" : moduleValue
    }
}, {
    multi : true
}).nModified);
```

When nModified == 0, all documents have been modified, and loop quits.
The downside for above code is: probably many times are needed to update a same document.
But it's thread safe.

---

## APPEND

The following code is compatible to MongoDB Version before V2.6

```
var searchArray = [ "AH Refer to CMC: Claims Inquiry",
        "AH Refer to CMC:  Eligibility Inquiry",
        "AH Refer to CMC: Requested Benefit Information",
        "After Hours - Referred to CMC", "After Hours Referred to RHBA" ];

var moduleValue = "Provider Search";

var query = {
        Values : {
            $elemMatch : {
                Reason : {
                    $in : searchArray
                },
                Modules : moduleValue
            }
        }
    };

var nCallUpdate = 0;

while ( db.ReasonTest_Kyle.findOne(query, {_id :1}) ) {
    db.ReasonTest_Kyle.update(query, {
        $pull : {
            "Values.$.Modules" : moduleValue
        }
    }, {
        multi : true
    });
    nCallUpdate++;
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying the result has no properties?  Further, the behavior I'm seeing is similar to what my solution produced.  It deletes the module "Provider Search" from the first one it matches, but all other ones it should delete are still there.

Comment: I noticed that you mentioned this might have to be run several times.  Would you mind explaining why this is the case?

Comment: @Kyle Richter, could you paste the full error message here?

Comment: @Kyle Richter, I test my code and it works well. I guess the version of your MongoDB is less than 2.6 which caused **.nModified** is not supported.

Comment: @Kyle Richter, `db.c.update({<array expression>}, {<locate element of array with $ sign>})` will modify at most one element of that array. So, in your case, if there are 3 elements conforming the query criteria, you have to update 3 times. That's why I used **while** statement.

Comment: @Kyle Richter, I append another part that is compatible with before V2.6.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I really appreciate it.  Further, thank you for your explanations.  I managed to get it working before you gave me the additional answer. :)

Comment: @Kyle Richter, my pleasure. :)